# Can't import Python modules after transferring to VSCode from PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pycharm, vscode-code-runner

My basic issue is that I get an error whenever I try to import a Python module in VSCode, which doesn't happen when using PyCharm.

From what I've read so far the problem seems to be with the python path, or the interpreter.
My issue is, that I don't really **understand** what the issue is, meaning I quickly feel lost when trying to apply some of the other solutions I have found, because I don't know what to look for.

Can someone clarify what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Edit: I probably forgot to add a crucial detail. I was facing this issue when running my python files using the code runner.
This is what I needed to add to my settings.json in order to get everything working completely:
"code-runner.executorMap": {
"python": "$enterPythonPathhere"
}

Comment: When you created your project in PyCharm did you set it to use your system interpreter or to make a virtual environment? and/or was VSCode using a venv? Chances are the environment its running in is different and so doesn't have the same modules available. If you go to file->settings then the Project: ProjectName tab, click "Python Interpreter" and you can add modules there. For modules whos name is the same as what you import (e.g. `requests`) you can usually just right click on where its underlined it in red and click to install the package there or under Context Actions in the rmb menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS Code press `Ctrl+Shift+P`
Type select interpreter in the search box

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

This will show a couple of environment paths. Click on the environment you were using in pycharm.

If your pycharm environment does show on the list you should enter the environment path instead. That should work.

Comment: Not sure wether this is still the same issue, but now I am getting the error "No module named...". If I go and try to install that module it tells me, that it is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

For installing and using python modules in VS Code, please refer to the following:

1. As people mentioned, select the desired python environment in the lower left corner of VS Code.
2. Please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, and then check whether it has entered the selected python environment.("python --version" or "pip --version")

   [image]
3. Install the module.
4. Check the installation of the module.(`pip show module_name`)

   [image]

Reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).